# use jQuery to set search field background colour if field has search term

Tags: jquery, css

Hi I have a table with a search field on most of the columns.

I would like to use jQuery to have the background of the search field change colour when a term has been entered, i.e. to change colour when it is not null or zero or has a count of 0 characters and remain changed for as long as the field has a search term.

The class of the fields whose background colour should be changed is

```
class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr"
```

I understand the convention is to have some code to begin with but I am very, very new to jQuery.

The CSS:

```
field.data {
    background-color: green;
}
```

The script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

//test if field tagged with class contains anything
//if it does set background
//if it doesn't unset background

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```js
$('.ui-state-default').blur(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == '') {
    $(this).removeClass('data');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('data');
  }
})
```

```css
.data {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="ui-state-default ui-th-column ui-th-ltr" />
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$('selector').css('background-color','colorvalue');
```

to change color

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I would like to check the content of the field and then make a color change based on a condition

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works fine

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

//test if field tagged with class contains anything
if($('selector').hasCLass('class-name')){
     if($(this).val()!=""){
    //if it does set background
    $(this).css('background-color','red');
    }
}else{
    //if it doesn't unset background
    $(this).css('background-color','transparent');

}



});
```